# Perl: string to an array reference?

Tags: arrays, perl

Say, there is a string `"[1,2,3,4,5]"`, how could I change it to an array reference as `[1,2,3,4,5]`? Using `split` and recomposing the array is one way, but it looks like there should be a simpler way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`eval` is the simplest way

```
$string = "[1,2,3,4,5]";
$ref = eval $string;
```

but this is insecure if you don't have control over the contents of `$string`.

Your input string is also valid JSON, though, so you could say

```
use JSON;
$ref = decode_json( $string );
```

Comment: How could I forget eval? Thanks a lot. I'll do a double check after 'eval' to ensure it's a 'ARRAY' reference.

Comment: @Yang You might want to do a double check _before_ `eval`. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `eval` but this should definitely be avoided when the string in question comes from untrusted sources.

Otherwise you have to parse it yourself:

```
my @arr = split(/\s*,\s*/, substr($string, 1, -1));
my $ref = \@arr;
```

Comment: I try to avoid using 'split', but the one is nice. Thanks.

Comment: @Yang: You have your priorities backwards. There is no reason to avoid using `split`, but `eval` is a dangerous sledgehammer that is rarely appropriate.

Comment: This is the right approach, but relies on the string being *exactly* as the OP shows, with no whitespace anywhere. The data may indeed be as tightly formatted as that, but if it is then there are *much* nicer ways of finding the values of the contained fields. An expression like `substr($string, 1, -1)` needs a comment, and good code should be able to stand on its own without comments.

Comment: @Borodin I modified the example to be slightly more forgiving about whitespace. I don’t know the exact requirements so I can’t do much more. Thanks for the comment, though.

Answer (score 2):

You really should avoid `eval` if you can. If the string comes from outside the program then untold damage can be done by simply applying `eval` to it.

If the contents of the array is just numbers then you can use a regex to extract the information you need.

Here's an example

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "[1,2,3,4,5]";
my $data   = [ $string =~ /\d+/g ];

use Data::Dump;
dd $data;
```

**output**

```
[1 .. 5]
```